# Problem with update laravel/Homestead from '7.2.1' to '10.1.0

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I tried to update my laravel/Homestead from '7.2.1' to '10.1.0' and encountered some problem

you can see below output what en error occured

```
$ vagrant box update
==> homestead-7: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead-7: Latest installed version: 7.2.1
    homestead-7: Version constraints: >= 4.0.0
    homestead-7: Provider: virtualbox
==> homestead-7: Updating 'laravel/homestead' with provider 'virtualbox' from version
==> homestead-7: '7.2.1' to '10.1.0'...
==> homestead-7: Loading metadata for box 'https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead'
==> homestead-7: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v10.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    homestead-7: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/10.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> homestead-7: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    homestead-7: Calculating and comparing box checksum...
The specified checksum type is not supported by Vagrant: sha512.
Vagrant supports the following checksum types:

md5, sha1, sha256
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Vagrant to the [latest version](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) – which supports sha512 checksums – before updating your Homestead box.